# Pandas Dataframe delete rows with false positives

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with a column Level. It has 2 values either easy or difficult. Sometimes between 100 rows with value 'Difficult' there appears 1 or 2 'Easy' values or vice versa, which are false positives.
For example,

```
  Level

  Difficult
  Difficult
  Difficult
  Difficult
  Easy
  Difficult
```

How can I get rid of this false positive values? But I want to keep it if it comes as a first value. For example,

```
    Level
  
    easy
    difficult
    difficult 
    difficult
```

Comment: So in other words, you want to change all `easy` values to `difficult`, EXCEPT the very first one?

Comment: exactly as how you say

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
df[df['Level'].eq('Difficult') | ~df['Level'].shift().isna()] = 'Difficult'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Level
0       Easy
1  Difficult
2  Difficult
3  Difficult
4       Easy
5  Difficult
6  Difficult

>>> df[df['Level'].eq('Difficult') | ~df['Level'].shift().isna()] = 'Difficult'
>>> df
       Level
0       Easy
1  Difficult
2  Difficult
3  Difficult
4  Difficult
5  Difficult
6  Difficult
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said sometimes it happens vice versa (Difficult false positives). Should I then apply this script again with value Easy instead of Difficult?

Comment: In that case is it mostly `Easy`, but there is an occasional `Difficult`?

Comment: yes. I have columns Level and Component. For some components it is like there are 100 difficult and 1-2 false easy values. But for some components it is vice versa. 100 easy values and 1-2 false dofficult values. But as I said i want to keep the value in the first row.

Comment: Yeah, then you should just swap the values in the code for that case.

Comment: E.g. `df[df['Level'].eq('Easy') | ~df['Level'].shift().isna()] = 'Easy'`

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: it does not work as desired unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239572/discussion-between-elgun-valiyev-and-user17242583).